# Ubuntu doesn't load after BIOS?

Tags: installation, boot

I have been trying to do figure out the wakeonlan options in BIOS and I just changed one option and restarted my system couples of times and now when I start it after HP BIOS logo it gives me blank screen and stuck there forever, I guess BIOS lost the OS path or something and it couldn't find it. Tried to install new Ubuntu and it shows the option

```
 Install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Ubuntu 13.10
```

That means I still have the Ubuntu on my system but I cant get to it, When I boot it from USB there is an option for disk check i tried this one too but didn't do any good.

#### Edit:

Tried making Boot Repair on bootable USB but when I hit `Recommended Repair` and it says

```
No Internet connection detected. Please connect Internet. Then try again.
```

I have proxy Internet so i don't know how to set its proxy for system, wondering why it has to connected to the Internet.. can't it do the job without Internet connection ?
Boot info summary says

```
 No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
```

here is the gparted Screen shot 
[image: Gparted]

Help !

Comment: did you try boot-repair?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I updated the question if you can look at that please :)

Comment: did you run boot-repair live disk?It shows like this but after that it shows boot-repair was successfully completed.

Comment: I followed the 1st option on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install grub2 on /dev/sda through **chroot** method.See this [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

Or

Try the second method on [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) page.

Comment: Tried the first link everything seems to work fine but when I reboot it does the same thing after that i even reset the BIOS but same thing .... tried the 2nd method on [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) page I get Internet problems because of proxy

Comment: upload gparted screenshot.

Comment: I uploaded the picture ! check it

Comment: you have any solution to this problem ? or i will have to reinstall my Ubuntu ?

Comment: i think it would help you http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/booting.html